# Difference between reversible and irreversible adiabatic process in PV diagram

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility, adiabatic, carnot-cycle

let's say we've got a carnot-cycle in a pressure volume diagram with the following processes:

1 -> 2: reversible isothermal

2 -> 3: reversible adiabatic

3 -> 4: reversible isothermal

4 -> 1: irreversible adiabatic

the diagram looks like this:

[image]

Now the question: How would the diagram look like if the last process was

4 -> 1: **reversible** adiabatic?

Comment: What if I told you that, in the irreversible compression, the pressure is not spatially uniform within the system?  What value of pressure would you plot on your diagram?  What if I also told you that, in an irreversible compression, the average pressure of the gas depends not only on the volume but also on the rate of change of volume.  How would you take this into account on your diagram.

Comment: As @ChesterMiller has pointed out, you cannot plot an irreversible path on a thermodynamic diagram. Usually such processes are shown _schematically_ by a broken line, which has no meaning besides indicating the fact that an irreversible process occurred between two equilibrium states. So when 4 to 1 process becomes reversible, what happens to your diagram is that a solid line will replace the broken line!

Comment: In addition to what @Zero said, I should mention that it is not possible to have and adiabatic reversible path and an adiabatic irreversible path between the same to end states.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram looks exactly how it should for a *reversible* process $4\to 1$. If the process is irreversible, on the other hand, the smooth solid line $4\to 1$ is deceptive, for it suggests that the system is passing through a sequence of equilibrium states in the process $4\to 1$. This is not the correct way to represent an *irreversible* process.

To clarify, for sure the system might possibly have at any time a definite pressure and volume in an irreversible process (although I fail to imagine at the present moment an *irreversible* and *adiabatic* process in which the $PVT$ system is also in mechanical equilibrium). But since a general irreversible path without any other constraint is quite arbitrary, I find it quite confusing to try to compare it with a definite reversible path like $pV^{\gamma}=\text {cost}$, without any other information.

Comment: I disagree. All that the diagram suggests is that there is a continuous sequence of states in the $p$-$v$ space that the system passes through. This is just as possible for irreversible processes as it is for reversible ones. There is no implication of equilibrium states. Note also that the concepts of "equilibrium process" and "isentropic process" are indeed orthogonal.

Comment: Hi @Pirx, this might be just a graphical issue, but the points in the $\text{P-V}$ diagram correspond to states in which the system has some definite pressure and volume, which is generally false (and meaningless) for a nonequilibrium state. Also, why do you say that "the concepts... are orthogonal"? And why do you say that the slope should be lower in the adiabatic case?

Comment: I realize I am going against (undergraduate) textbook wisdom here, but what I was trying to say is that we can most certainly draw a curve in a, say, $p$-$v$ diagram for any system, equilibrium or not, as long as we define what those $p$ and $v$ values mean. Thus, if we agree to simply show the volume-averaged pressure as a function of the specific volume, then there is no issue. I realize that this is not adhering to standard textbook rules, so that your answer may indeed be the one that was expected from the OP in his/her homework... ;-)

Comment: Continued: As for my comment on "orthogonal concepts": It is possible to have equilibrium processes that are isentropic or non-isentropic, and it is possible to have isentropic non-equilibrium processes.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply any categorical rule for drawing diagrams, however I see your point. However I find it quite strange to ask to compare an adiabatic reversible path with a non-reversible one, which might in principle be quite arbitrary. For example, the fact that you say, that the slope should be lower in the reversible path (which I guess comes from the fact $\text d s>0$) must surely break down at some point, if the irreversible path has to end in the same point as the reversible one

Comment: Oh yes, in the end it means that either the point 1 or 4, or both, must be different. If we assume point 1 as given and fixed, then point 4 would have to move down and to the right along the 3-4 curve. And of course, you are right that the true path will be arbitrary to a large degree once the condition of reversibility is dropped.

Answer (score 0):

The reversible adiabatic process 4-1 would be *isentropic*, $\mbox{d}s=0$. For an ideal gas such a process is described by a curve given by $p\,v^\gamma=\mbox{const.}$, with $\gamma$ the ratio of specific heats. The curve would look somewhat similar to the one for 2-3, and somewhat "flatter" (lower absolute value of slope) compared to what you have in your diagram now.